# Impala concurrent query delay

Tags: impala, apache-kudu

**My cluster configuration is as follows:**

1. 3 Node cluster
2. 128GB RAM per cluster node.
3. Processor: 16 core HyperThreaded per cluster node.
   All 3 nodes have Kudu master and T-Server and Impala server, one of the node has Impala catalogue and Impala StateStore.

**My issues are as follows:**

1) I've a hard time figuring out Dynamic resource pooling in Impala while running concurrent queries. I've tried giving **mem_limit** still no luck. I've also tried static service pool but with that also I couldn't achieve required concurrency. Even with admission control, the required concurrency was not achieved.

```
 I) The time taken for 1 query: 500-800ms.

 II) But if 10 concurrent queries are given the time taken grows to 3-6s per query.

 III) But if more than 20 concurrent queries are given the time taken is exceeding 10s per query.
```

2) One of my cluster nodes is not taking the load after submitting the query, I checked this by the summary of the query. I've tried giving the **NUM_NODES** as 0 and 1 on the node which is not taking the load, still, the summary shows that the node is not taking the load.

Comment: The machine which is not taking the load is accessible from from other 2?

Comment: @SaifAhmad yes. It is accessible from the other nodes.

Comment: Are you executing the same query in parallel? In that case you may be experiencing "hot-spotting" if the replication factor for your Kudu table is 1, for example.

Comment: No, replication factor is set to 3 and we are not running the same query in parallel. There are more than 100 different queries which are executed.

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into your performance numbers.  Impala is MPP and not designed to run on a 3 node cluster.  Most benchmarks run on at least a 10 node cluster with a total of 1TB memory or more.

Comment: @tk421 thank you for your reply but can you tell me how can I manage resource pool in impala so that I can execute concurrent queries in Impala?

Answer (score 0):

What is the table size ? How many rows are there in the tables ? Are the tables partitioned ? It will be nice if you can compare your configurations with the Impala Benchmarks

As mentioned above Impala is designed to run on a Massive Parallel Processing Infrastructure. If when we had a setup of 10 nodes with 80 cores and 160 virtual cores with 12 TB SAN storage, we could get a computation time of 60 seconds with 5 concurrent users.